# Critique: Amateur looking buttons with icons?

Tags: icon, interface-design, critique, button

I am working on a CMS with the feature to 'follow' and also the option to see stats.

There are 2 buttons, and the stats value becomes 1.2k etc after it reaches over 1000.

I have added some icons, and trying to keep the design flat and simple but something doesn't feel right.

Im going to try making the icons smaller, but other than that, any ideas?

Perhaps icon on the right?

[image]

EDIT, I am going to run a test where by I remove the text and simply have the heart and the stats button. I'll have a tool top when hovering, and it might also make things more consistent when the media queries kick in.

Comment: Hm. Depending a little on the rest of the layout, I do not see much wrong with them. I would have played a little with gentle colour variation on the icons... but have not a lot of other good ideas.

Comment: I don't see any problems with them either! I actually like them a lot.

Comment: They look fine to me too - though the vertical alignment is a touch off (the text is a bit low of centre and the heart is lower than the chart). Maybe that's what doesn't feel right?

Answer (score 6):

There is a certain point in a long design process where it's easy to fall into the trap of overthinking what you're doing. Different parts of the design seem like they could be better, you aren't sure how, exactly, but maybe if... At that point, you begin an endless (and pointless) round of tweaks that as often as not end up uglifying what was fine to start with.

I suspect that's where you are now, because that looks as fine to me as it does to Yisela and boblet. I would counsel taking a long step back, spending some quality time with the cat/dog/iguana, and coming back to it after you've put some mental distance between you and all the detailed work you've been doing. Look at it freshly, from about 9 feet (3 metres -- gotta keep up with metric) away, as if you'd never seen it before. If anything really needs a fix, you'll see it clearly.

There's an old artists' trick of looking at a painting or drawing in the mirror, to get a fresh perspective on it. This is a variation on that theme.

Comment: +1. 100% agree, and points for the iguana and metric :) There are a few other artisty methods: ignore it for three days, look at your work upside down, print it out, spend some time looking at nice abstract art (I am happy to provide some:), make a tiiiny little hole with thumbs and forefingers and look at your work through that. If all these fail, do some astro-gymnastics :D http://visualsquirrel.wordpress.com/2014/03/27/piet-hein-astro-gymnastics/